# How to get random entity from SQL Server with a lambda expression and the entity can once come

Tags: c#, lambda

I want to get a random entity from SQL Server with a lambda expression, but I don't want to return with `StudentID`, I want to return with order.

For example id = 3, order = 4 can be, because I can remove that entity.

```
    void RandomSelectStudent()
    {
        Random rnd = new Random();
        _studentService .GetAll().;
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

i'll go ahead and say your question is seriously mal-formed, however, if i'm guessing right, you want an order of students starting at a random position.

```
Random random = new Random();
var count = await db.Students.CountAsync();
var take = whatever you want here baby;
var skip = random.Next(0, count);
var sequenceYouWant = await 
    db.Students.Skip(skip).Take(take).ToWhateverYouWantBaby();
```

Comment: I found it  ,    var student = _studentService.GetAll().Where(x => x.isActive).OrderBy(c => Guid.NewGuid()).FirstOrDefault()      , Thank you for the help

Comment: @clleker I think that `.GetAll()` is going to load every student into memory, assign them a new guid, then sort them, then take the first one. Will be far more efficient to use `.Skip()` and `.Take()`